# Java: repeated calls to paintAll hangs program

Tags: java, awt, paint

I'm implementing video capture in a Java program by creating `BufferedImage`s at a user-defined interval (for my testing, 100ms), and then using those images to make a movie file. The `JFrame` that I am trying to record from includes a dashboard-like interface contained by a `JLayeredPane`. The `JFrame` also has two `Canvas3D`s. I'm telling each of these 3 things to `render` or `paint` into their own `LinkedBlockingDeque<BufferedImage>`, and I combine them later. The dashboard is set to only render every `dashboardFrameRepaintFrequency` frames.

```
Thread captureThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final Object LOCK = new Object();
            final Thread captureDashboard = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (m_isCapturingMovie) {
                        synchronized (LOCK) {
                            try {
                                LOCK.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                System.err.println("Calling getDashboardImage");
                                m_unsavedDash.add(getDashboardImage(m_dashboard.getWidth(), m_dashboard.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
                                System.err.println("captureDashboard returned from calling m_unsavedDash.add...");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            captureDashboard.start();

            while (m_isCapturingMovie) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                captureCanvases();
                if (++frameCount > dashboardFrameRepaintFrequency) {
                    frameCount = 0;
                    synchronized (LOCK) {
                        LOCK.notify();
                    }
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            millisToSleep = captureDelayInMillis - (endTime - startTime);
            if (millisToSleep > 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(millisToSleep);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        synchronized (captureDashboard) {
        captureDashboard.notify();
        }
    }
});
```

I've found that after 15-20 `notify()`s, the program locks up - it stops recording the Canvases, stops responding to keyboard input.. I can still change which window has focus, and the buttons (such as the X button to close a window) still change visual state from mouse rollover or clicking, but they don't execute their commands.

From the console output, it seems that the captureDashboard thread, after those 15-20 iterations, does not return from the `getDashboardImage` method:

```
private BufferedImage getDashboardImage(int width, int height, int type) {
    BufferedImage dashImg = new BufferedImage(m_dashboard.getWidth(), m_dashboard.getHeight(), type);
    Graphics2D g = dashImg.createGraphics();
    m_dashboard.paintAll(g);
    g.dispose();

    return getScaledImage(width, height, dashImg);
}

private BufferedImage getScaledImage(int width, int height, BufferedImage original) {
    BufferedImage scaled = new BufferedImage(width, height, original.getType());

    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale((double) scaled.getWidth() / original.getWidth(), (double) scaled.getHeight() / original.getHeight());
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp;
    if (at.getScaleX() + at.getScaleY() > 2.0) {
        scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC); // Better quality for enlargement
    } else {
        scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR); // Better quality for ensmallment
    }

    scaled = scaleOp.filter(original, scaled);
    original.flush();
    return scaled;
}
```

Any ideas? I've been working at this for a few days and I'm stumped.

Comment: +1 A first post that's actually well formatted, not asinine and effort was obviously put into it.  Welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Maybe OP did the formatting because for the first time I am having problem also posting the answer with formatting. For some weird reason, the formatting gets lost. Tried different ways but couldn't get it to work in my last answer.

Comment: @SajalDutta I can almost guarantee it's because you were using tabs, which become 8 spaces, instead of just having 4 actual spaces. 99% of the problems with code formatting in questions are because of that.

Comment: Is there a reason that you aren't just using the `Robot` class? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image). All you'd do is just limit the rectangle passed to the screenshot method to the rectangle of your window. Plus, this uses native code so will be much faster.

Comment: @Brian, no tab as tab doesn't work (or I am wrong) in SO editor. Let me try again.

Comment: @Brian I tried copying my answer in notepad++ to see if there's any tab. None. All 4 spaces each. Doesn't work. See- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750575/flelwriter-in-java-not-writing-to-txt-file/17750611#17750611

Comment: @Brian `Robot` had too much of a performance impact on the program - everything ran much slower from the user's perspective AND the actual captured frame rate was much worse (about half the fps of rendering extra frames).

Comment: @SajalDutta I might have messed up by using pasted tabs. I just replaced them with four spaces. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to call `paintAll` from the AWT dispatch thread.

So instead of:

```
m_dashboard.paintAll(g);
```

I needed to have:

```
final Graphics2D g = dashImg.createGraphics();

EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run () {
        m_dashboard.paintAll(g);
    }
});
```

This, however, caused my program to "get ahead of itself" and return the `BufferedImage` before it had been painted to, but ONLY if the program was under heavy load. To account for this, I just added the following:

```
final Graphics2D g = dashImg.createGraphics();
final SyncObj LOCK = new SyncObj();

EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run () {
        m_dashboard.paintAll(g);
        LOCK.doNotify();
    }
});

LOCK.doWait();
g.dispose();
```

Where SyncObj is just a simple:

```
class SyncObj {
    private boolean condition = false;
    private Object obj = new Object();

    public void doWait() {
        synchronized (obj) {
            while (!condition) {
                try {
                    obj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            condition = false;
        }
    }

    public void doNotify() {
        synchronized (obj) {
            condition = true;
            obj.notify();
        }
    }
}
```